# why it's OK to access protected variable in base class from derived instance

Tags: c++, inheritance, copy, accessibility

The following snippet makes me feel puzzled.
Why is der._x++ correct ? 
As it's a temporary local variable copied from Derived argument.
It should only have accessibility to the public members. 
the commented statement bs._x++ cannot pass which should be correct.
Please let me know where I misunderstand! Thank you in advance!

Thank you for your kind answers. But my doubt is that der is an Derived object copied from the argument, in other words, it should be considered as a client that use the initialized Derived object. It is not the *this instance but another temporary instance which results from copy constructor.

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base(int x, int y) :_x(x), _y(y){}
protected:
    int _x, _y;
};

class Derived :public Base
{
public:
    Derived(int x, int y,int z) :Base(x,y), _z(z){}
    void mem1(Base bs, Derived der) //copy constructor called. Derived::Derived(const Derived &)
    {
        der._x++;
        //bs._x++;
        _x++;
    }
private:
    int _z;
};

    int main()
    {
        Derived der(6,4,3), der1(5,3,2);
        Base bs(-5,-4);
        der1.mem1(bs, der);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Because that's how the language works. Access isn't just to one's `this` instance.

Comment: `protected` is there for exactly that. `protected` members can be accessed by derived classes, `private` cannot.

Comment: if you want the derived class can't access the parent class's member variable please mark them under private.

Answer (score 0):

`der._x++` is **accessible** because `_der` is an **object of the same `Derived` class** and you're accessing `_x` from inside the `Derived` class.

While you're inside a class, you can access its members (with or without object reference). Otherwise `(*this)._x` will be disallowed too which isn't :)

But you cannot do the same for any other class which is the case for `bs._x++` hence it is not allowed.

`Friends` heavily rely on this feature of the language for their implementation. Also not to forget `Singleton` cannot be implement without it (as you call its `private constructor` from inside the class).